# Restore neo4j graph from a huge dump

Tags: neo4j

I have a huge dump of my graph in a file (i.e. 550k lines of CRATEs) and I need to restore it. I tried from terminal

neo4j-shell -file backup.cypher

...but after 24 hours the transaction was not committed, then I stopped it.

Is there another way to restore my data?

Answer (score 2):

You can split your dump file to multiple files and run restore for each of it.

But be aware there could be references between CREATE clauses.

Comment: I'm just trying this strategy. The good news is that the dump contains first the CREATE clauses of nodes and then the clauses of relationships. The bad news is that I'm trying with a 50k-clauses file and after 20 minutes, it is still crunching...:(

Comment: Does not work. My dump is too huge. The only way is moving data through binary files into graph.db folder : /

Answer (score 1):

Split up the creates into individual ones, separated by semicolon.
then wrap 50k of them each into a `begin ... commit` block.

for the relationships, change them to a match + match + create statement to find the two nodes and create the relationship.